# jQuery | Using globals variables in this small snippet

Tags: jquery, variables, global

i'd like to use these variables globally.
the resize function does not work. only if i copy the variables.
i want to use this code inside a document ready function.

thanks for your help.

```
    var pageWidth       = $('#page').width(),
        pageWidthFifth  = pageWidth / 5,
        wrapAndSidebar  = $('#sidebar-wrap, #sidebar');

    wrapAndSidebar.width(pageWidthFifth);


    $(window).resize(function(){

        wrapAndSidebar.width(pageWidthFifth);

    });
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the HTML markup for this, but I assume that you want to change the width of the sidebar based on the width of the `#page` element? If that's the case, you must define those variables in a local content, for example inside a function. At the moment they are being populated upon page load and remain the same all the time.

Comment: yes i wanna do this. just wondering how could i solve the problem not copy and pasting the variables again inside the resize function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap everything in a function:

```
function resizeSidebar() {

    var pageWidth   = $('#page').width(),
    pageWidthFifth  = pageWidth / 5,
    wrapAndSidebar  = $('#sidebar-wrap, #sidebar');

    wrapAndSidebar.width(pageWidthFifth);

}

resizeSidebar();

$( window ).resize( function() {

    resizeSidebar();

} );
```

Please note I haven't tested this code in the browser, but it's pretty much what you must do. The idea is that all the variables are being re-populated on screen resize with their *current* values rather than the original ones.